# when using MASM, is ECX automatically initialized?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, masm

I use VS2012 and MASM.
When I shell my program, ECX is always set to 0x00000000 whatever I want to do in main function. I checked this mystery on other computers, but the result is always same(ECX=0x00000000). Other registers like EAX, EBX are not initialized automatically. What makes ECX initialized?

Comment: Nothing to do with MASM. This is just an artifact of the way that the Windows operating system loads executables, and is therefore tied to the specific version of Windows. It is not portable, and not something that you can rely on. You need to initialize all registers. If you haven't, assume that they contain garbage (even if it happens that that garbage is usually zero).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering how the program works right although I forgot to initialize ECX register. You told me the reason exactly.